# Retractable Thumb Drive is Stuck

Tags: storage

I have been using my Retractable Thumb Drive for 10+ years.

It is stuck and and tried pushing, pulling, praying --- nothing worked!

How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: So the solution depends on if you want to keep using the same device or just get the info off it onto a new one?

Comment: SanDisk has astonishing support. I'd start with them. Who better? Saved my donkey more than once. Good Luck.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you can get lucky and by using a pin, inserted from the push tab in between the red and black parts, pushing toward the front. The mechanism will give way and the USB port will slide out.

Sometimes you are not so lucky and it's stuck for good, if this is the case.... Use a small craft knife and cut around the seals where the plastic is joined, usually right down the center all the way round. When cut enough you should be able to pop the plastic shell off exposing the internals.

At this point be sure to touch a tap to discharge any static electrical charge in your body before you touch the storage device directly.

Remove the device carefully, pop it into a USB port on your computer and copy thr data off.

Buy a new drive. Thanks the old one for its years of service and bin jt, you could day a prayer for it and send it off on a burning raft so it will make the journey to Valhalla safely .

Hope this helps
Good luck

Comment: the plastic pry tools sold for opening phones and other sealed electronics would work here as as well and could be less risky than a metal blade.

Comment: True however the brand featured here has the two haves molded together when made. i.e. Not just clipped together. Only way I found to get them off is to cut through there is no going back once you are done. ( Well except for some electrical tape :P )